# Spring Boot: Flyway migration before mybatis initialization

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

In my Spring Boot app I use Flyway for DB migrations and MyBatis together. **Problem is that MyBatis is initialized before Flyway**, so some **DB operations are called** (within @PostConstruct) **before DB migration**.

If I take a look into **FlywayAutoConfiguration** there is:

```
@AutoConfigureAfter({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, ...})
public class FlywayAutoConfiguration { 
  ...
```

As I understand, I need override FlywayAutoConfiguration and add:

```
@AutoConfigureAfter({DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureBefore({MybatisAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FlywayAutoConfiguration { 
  ...
```

Not sure how to do that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a `@Bean` definition for `flyway()` and then another `@Bean` definition for whatever data source in your possession, making sure to initialize it after the flyway bean , which you can simply do by adding `@DependsOn("flyway")` annotation on your data source bean declaration.

This way you make sure whatever data init tasks launched by your data source will come after flyway has done its job.